# Wrap XML sibling tags in a parent tag with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a set of sibling tags that look like this in a much larger document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <a>some text</a>, '<b>some text</b>', <c><d>some text</d> <e>sometext</e></c>
</foo>
```

The requirement is that the transform matches tag a followed by "," followed by tag b, then tag c.  These are then wrapped in an outer tag.  Below is a simplified representation of what I would like the document to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar><a>some text</a>, `<b>some text</b>', <c><d>some text</d> <e>sometext</e></c></bar>
</foo>
```

However, I want this to be done *in place* in a much larger document without disturbing any other tags.

Basically, I am attempting to match the pattern above in the nodes in the document then wrap the pattern in a parent tag and delete the old nodes so I do not have duplicates in the output.  Is there away to do that cleanly in XSLT?

Comment: Part of that requirements to wrap adjacent siblings is (given XSLT 2 or 3) often a use case for `xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent`. It is not quite clear from your input and lack of textual explanation of the requirement whether that will work for you. Posting code that doesn't do the job is usually not a good way to communicate to use what you want to achieve. It certainly doesn't help to use a new mode to prevent the existing mode doing an identity transformation to not copy certain nodes, you will need to use that existing mode and add empty templates for the siblings you wrap elsewhere.

Comment: I have attempted to amend the question as per your suggestions.  I hope this makes it more clear what I am attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Can these siblings occur in any kind of element? What if there are more of them, will all be wrapped into a single `bar` or any single sequence of the shown node into a `bar` wrapper of their own?

Comment: Yes, they can occur pretty much anywhere in the document.  Any single sequence will have a `bar` wrapper of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of an odd sequence so all I have been able to come with is a bit of an odd combination of a `for-each-group group-starting-with` plus `for-each-group group-adjacent` (delegating the check to a function you probably need to adjust to check your nodes exactly as you expect them):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:adjacent-predicate" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:param name="pos" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="$pos eq 1 and $node instance of element(a) or
              $pos = (2,4) and $node instance of text() and contains($node, ',') or
              $pos eq 3 and $node instance of element(b) or
              $pos eq 5 and $node instance of element(c)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[a]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="a">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::a">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="mf:adjacent-predicate(., position())">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <bar>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </bar>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>          
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree it is something out of the ordinary.  It is late where I am so I will try this against the document that I have and let you know if this helped. Thank you!